# Use native Php session (configured via php.ini) with Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony, session

My php is configured to use memcache session, it's working fine without symfony.

But, with Symfony, I didnt manage to use it "easily", it's always use native-file, is it possible to use php.ini?

php info:

```
Registered save handlers    "files user memcached"
Registered serializer handlers  "php_serialize php php_binary"
session.save_handler    "memcached"
session.save_path   "X-memcache:11213"
```

Comment: Have you read this https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/components/http_foundation/session_configuration.html ?

Comment: As well as the session configuration section: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#session